# Facebook comment box locale

Tags: locale, facebook-comments

Am I allowed to change facebook comment box locale?
I have the following code on my test website
Looks like it's working, but im not sure its allowed.

I have changed `en_US` to `he_IL` in the script below.

Please advise.

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/he_IL/all.js#xfbml=1"; // Here!
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've done (inserting the desired locale into the script path) is exactly the first step towards internationalization as recommended by Facebook when using social plugins with XFBML.

According to their [Internationalization Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/):

> If you're using XFBML, you need to load the JavaScript SDK in the appropriate locale for your site. For example, if your site is in Spanish, reference this script:
>
> ```
> //connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js
> ```

So it looks like yes, it is allowed and you are on the right track.